# Foundation 5 - div fill height

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to fill my sidebar div so the blue background fills the screen. Foundation makes this slightly tricky (I have tried height:100%;)

[image: Screenshot]

http://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/olduj

```
<ul class="side-nav" link="white">
<li class="active"><a href="#">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of three different ways to achieve this.

- Set the height of the parent elements (`body`/`html`) to `100%`. In doing so, you can set the child's height to `100%`.

  ```
  html, body, .side-nav { height: 100%; }
  ```
- Use [viewport percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). In this case you would use `100vh`.

  ```
  .side-nav { height: 100vh; }
  ```
- Absolutely position the element and specify a `top`/`bottom` value of `0`.

  ```
  .side-nav { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; }
  ```

  If that doesn't work, you would have to try `fixed` positioning. (It's worth pointing out that `fixed` positioning is relative to the window, whereas `absolute` positioning is relative to the closest non-`static`ly positioned parent element.)

Comment: Thanks, I used the viewport percentage lengths as the other ones didn't work.